# How can I find Nilpotent Matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I trying to find nilpotent matrix formula for python with Numpy library.I will use specific matrix (3x3) and I will check the matrix if it nilpotent or not. What should I do ?

Comment: Tell us what `nilpotent` is.  It does not appear anywhere in the `numpy` docs, so you have to bring outside knowledge to the task.

Comment: @hpaulj ("A square matrix A is called a nilpotent matrix, if A^m=0 for some positive integer m.")

Answer (score 0):

A matrix is nilpotent if and only if the only eigenvalue it has is 0. Therefore you can just do something like the following:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[1,0,-1]])
w, v = LA.eig(A)
```

The vector w will contain the eigenvalues while v will contain the eigenvectors. Now just check if w only has the 0 eigenvalue and then you are done.

Comment: How I check it, I tried with for loop but it didn't work